# Spherical harmonics

Tags: asymptote, physics

For my lecture notes I need to visualize spherical harmonics in Asymptote.
Using the notes from https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalHarmonic.html

```
triple fs(pair p){
real x=sin(p.x)*cos(p.y)*(sqrt(3/(4*pi))*sin(p.x)*cos(p.y))^2;
real y=sin(p.x)*sin(p.y)*(sqrt(3/(4*pi))*sin(p.x)*cos(p.y))^2;
real z=cos(p.x)*(sqrt(3/(4*pi))*sin(p.x)*cos(p.y))^2;
return (x,y,z);
}
surface s=surface(fs,(0,pi),(0,2pi),100);
draw(s);
```

Comment: What is the question/the problem?

Comment: I don't understand how to accurately and correctly draw spherical harmonics pictures in 3D in asymptote

Comment: thank you I found nice example of spherical Harmonics in Asymptote on  https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/gallery